# Convert time to client local time in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime

if i have some time with UTC now. which coming from backend in json format like:

```
cache_time: "2019-04-29 06:12:06"
```

and eg. some user will open page in some another country or city. How i can convert it to this user time with javascript?

Comment: Hi what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string with "2019-04-29 06:12:06" does not indicate the time zone. If you add a 'Z' at the end, the built in Date function understands that the time is in UTC.

```js
const cache_time = "2019-04-29 06:12:06";

const date = new Date ( cache_time + "Z" );
console.log("UTC TIME", date.toISOString())
console.log("LOCAL TIME", date.toLocaleString() );
```

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan There is no need to call `Date.parse` since `Date` will parse the argument since it is a string.

Comment: sorry i just want to edit my answer and edit yours by mistake

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan Ok :) Happy editing!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Moment.js libary:

```js
date = new Date("2019-04-29 06:12:06Z");

var withoutUTC = moment(date).toString();
var withUTC = moment.utc(date).toString();
console.log(withoutUTC)
console.log(withUTC)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's mean this date 2019-04-29 06:12:06 so when time was 06:12:06 on my computer my time was a 03:12:06 right ?

Comment: No, this gives a date and time in the users time-zone. Add a 'Z' to the end of the timestamp, and Date will understand that it is UTC and will display it in the users timezone.

Comment: [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: @user3348410 what output you expect ?

Comment: I understand that: it's give me difference with utc time and my local time. so +03.00 hours. Everything well. But how i can show it like 2019-04-29  ' here sum of this difference time' eg: if utc is 12:00 and difference 3 hour  i would show it like: 2019-04-29  15:00

Comment: @user3348410 you want to show the date part only?

Comment: No i want to show updated date and time with difference. So more readable 2019-04-29 06:12:06 like this. just calculated version with difference

Comment: @user3348410 check

Answer (score -1):

Use moment.js to convert utc to local time.In your case:
`moment().utc("2019-04-29 06:12:06").local().format()`

Comment: It's give me "2019-04-29T18:40:24+03:00" something like this. i didn't understand what is this mean

Comment: what date time object you passed to moment?

Answer (score -2):

Or you can use spacetime.js, which is based on moment.js and takes into consideration also timezones. `const localTimeDate = spacetime().now().format();`